# Drop D power chords

Tags: guitar, chords, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, mute

I have difficulties in taking power chords in Drop D tuning. Basically, in standard tuning I would mute other strings with my index finger, but here I have difficulty in barring three strings and mute other three. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Please also look at http://music.stackexchange.com/q/4070/104 - good guidance on the common ways to mute strings.

Answer (score 4):

With the electric guitar, I make the power chords using just the index finger to press the 6th, 5th and 4th strings. With the rest of your index finger you can mute the top three strings, and you still have the other fingers to add more notes if you ever need them.

It might be a little more difficult doing that on an acoustic guitar because of the string tension, but I still think it's the easiest way.

Answer (score 3):

By using your  middle, ring and little finger on 6th, 5th and 4th strings respectively, you can still use the index finger to mute the top three strings.Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can press strings 4,5 and 6 with finger 1, and mute strings 1,2 and 3 with finger 3 or finger 4 (about 2 frets up from finger 1)

Answer (score 3):

You might have to change a bit the way you're strumming the strings.
As you're only playing on the bottom 3 strings, you should focus on your strumming hand in order to reduce your movement, maybe you go too far. This is not a "full chord" strumming, you should stop your movement sooner in order to avoid touching the 3 string you don't want to play.

Moreover you just have to train in order to release pressure on the other 3 strings in order to mute them with the same finger (the same exercise you need to do to play a proper A chord with one finger).

Combine this "light" muting and a reduced strumming movement and you should be able to play nice Drop D powerchords.

Comment: Bottom 3 strings !

Comment: @Tim It depends on how you see it, if you're looking at the strings while standing, it's the top ones :). But I'll fix it, thanks.
KudayarPirimbaev : Yes, but if playing was easy it would be less fun :). I guess it depends on people and how you learned to play, because I never had this issue when playing in Drop D.

Comment: Yes they're on top, but they play lower sounds, therefore bottom !. I stopped calling them top/bottom, always refer to thick or thin. No confusion !!

Answer (score 0):

it just takes practice, only use your first finger, lay it across all six strings and practice pushing down the top three strings and resting the rest of your finger against the higher strings so they're muted.

Your finger just needs time to learn the position - it's called muscle memory. You can do it with multiple fingers but it'll be slower.

Also focus on just strumming the top three strings